# Is there a way to download an audio file of all the audio streams playing on a particular page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm building an application using PizzicatoJS + HowlerJS. Those libraries essentially allow me to play multiple audio files at the same time. Imagine a 4 audio tracks with each track containing an instrument like guitar, bass, drums, vocals, etc..

Everything plays fine when using PizzicatoJS's Group functionality or running a `forEach` loop on all my Howl sounds and firing `.play()`. However, I would like to download the final resulting sound I am hearing from my speakers. Any idea on how to approach that?

I looked into OfflineAudioContext, but I am unsure on how to use it to generate an audio file. It looks like it needs an Audio source like an `<audio>` tag. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OfflineAudioContext can help with your use case.

Let's say you want to create a file with a length of 10 seconds. It should contain one sound playing from the start up to second 8. And there is also another sound which is supposed to start at second 5 and should last until the end. Both sounds are AudioBuffers (named `soundBuffer` and `anotherSoundBuffer`) already.

You could arrange and combine the sounds as follows.

```
const sampleRate = 44100;
const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext({
    length: sampleRate * 10,
    sampleRate
});

const soundSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode({
    buffer: soundBuffer
});

soundSourceNode.start(0);
soundSourceNode.stop(8);
soundSourceNode.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);

const anotherSoundSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode({
    buffer: anotherSoundBuffer
});

anotherSoundSourceNode.start(5);
anotherSoundSourceNode.stop(10);
anotherSoundSourceNode.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);

offlineAudioContext
    .startRendering()
    .then((audioBuffer) => {
        // save the resulting buffer as a file
    });
```

Now you can use a library to turn the resulting AudioBuffer into an encoded audio file. One library which does that is for example [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav).

Comment: How do I generate a useable buffer? I have tried doing an XHR call => arrayBuffer => decodeAudioData. However, when I use the AudioBuffer from that in const soundSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode({
    buffer: soundBuffer
}) I get a ton of errors in my console.

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression that you already have the AudioBuffers. Your approach looks right. This is some example code which shows how to get an AudioBuffer from a file: https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/. I hope it helps.